# Visual C++ Statictext "&" Symbol

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, msvcrt

I have a very small problem with Visual C++: when I try to put a word or sentence contaning a `&` symbol into static text, I see that `&` symbol as `_` on the screen.

Thanks for any help.

```
int CustomerID;

CString Str= m_lv1.GetItemText(iItem, 0); Str.TrimLeft(); Str.TrimRight();      

//if the Str "Hello & Hi" it shows "Hello _ Hi"
m_CustomerName.SetWindowText(Str);
```

Answer (score 3):

MSVC uses `&` to denote the underlined letter used for menus and other widgets, the one you can use with Alt to control your UI via keyboard. A double `&&` should represent a single `&` in the text, iirc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C or C++. It's a convention of the Windows common controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use '&&' for a single & (that does not act as shortcut), or set the [SS_NOPREFIX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) style to supress ampersand handling completely.